# How to grant permission to use specific Application Page in SharePoint

Tags: permissions, application-pages, spuser

I have custom application page, now what I want to do, is to allow users ( or SPGroup ) to view and use application page. How this should be done ? Currently only administrator can view application page, other users can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figure this out. The problem was that I was accessing SPSite and SPWeb objects, and users didn't have permissions to interact with this objects. So I had to wrap SPSite and SPWeb object calls into SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges. Now everything works as exepcted.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have in your codebehind

```
 protected override bool RequireSiteAdministrator {
    get { return false; }
  }
```

Then in your Init event, you can check if the current user is member of a specific group that you trust and if it's not the case, you can use the `SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("Your relevant access denied message")`

Comment: Hi, I have added RequireSiteAdministrator in code-behind, but I still got the same error ( Access is denied ). I'm not checking anything in Init method as you proposed ( not yet ) I just want to make sure that users other than admin can access my page as well. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Can you give us an overview of your code to check which class you're inheriting ? It might be an administration page rather than an application page.

Comment: It's application page, here is definition


public partial class Reports : LayoutsPageBase
{
}